# Video.js: Big button for quiz in video.js 7.8.2

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

servas,

Is there a way to add big buttons to the `video.js-plugin` to answer questions during a video?

I succeeded to add a button to the control bar by adding

```
player.getChild('controlBar').addChild('answer1Button', {});
```

but I need 1 (to 3) BIG buttons at the center of the video like the BigPlayButton at the beginning - what's the correct component to add?

as an alternative: what's the correct way to show the control bar all the time (and not to automatically hide it)?

ciao
H.